# What is a file based database?

Tags: database, file

I am enrolled in a course about relational databases. I was asked to research the advantage of a file based approach versus relational databases.

I find it easier to understand relational databases but having difficulty understanding file based systems. Are file based systems the same as storing files on a windows hierarchical system, meaning text files stored under folders and directories? Are plain csv files an example of file based system?

Comment: Your question shows no research or effort that you have made to understand it. please do some research before you question here. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir This is the first item that comes up on google when you type "file based database" into google, so it's maybe just a good idea to have this question as a decent stack overflow resource.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we refer to file-based databases we mean databases that we interact with/update directly (via an SQL abstraction offered by the JDBC driver) but in essence we just read/write to a file directly. Example would be SQLite

No, CSV is a comma separated values file which allows data to be saved in a table structured format.

A "flat file" database allows the user to specify data attributes (columns, datatypes, etc) for one table at a time, storing those attributes independantly of an application. dBase III and Paradox were good examples of this kind of database in the CP/M and MS-DOS environments, and the original FileMaker was a good Mac O/S example.

A relational database takes this "flat file" approach several logical steps further, allowing the user to specify information about multiple tables and the relationships between those tables, and often allowing much more declarative control over what rules the data in those tables must obey.

Database systems are mechanisms that mediate between file systems and an API based on RDBMS principles. Without getting into detail about the specific sets of rules that together make up an RDBMS, we can say that these mostly provide a way to organize and access information stored in files.
The most noticeable features of databases compared with raw file-systems are structure and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

File based database was firstly introduced in **1968**. In file based database, data was maintained in a **flat-file**. Though files have many advantages, there are several limitations.
One of the major advantages is that the file based system has various access methods, e.g., sequential, indexed and random.
It requires extensive programming language in third generation language such as COBOL,BASIC.