# File based approach to storing data vs Database approach

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have read that Access is not as secure and fast as using SQL database because it uses file based approach to storing data to the disk. I don't quite understand what are the differences between the file based approach vs database approach

Comment: AFAIK, Access is a database https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-file-system-and-a-database and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268664/what-is-a-file-based-database Perhaps what you are really asking about is the difference between file server and client server? https://itstillworks.com/file-server-vs-client-server-7487743.html

Answer (score 2):

Comparison between the two approaches as below -

**File based approach**
Each program defines,manages and maintains its own data.
Data is scattered and users of one program doesn't know if there is any useful data held by other programs. 
File structure is defined in the application program code therefore Programs are written to satisfy particular functions/application.

**Database approach**
Shared collection of logically related data which can be shared among application. 
It Improves maintenance,reduce data redundancy and Increased productivity.

Answer (score 0):

File-based approach Refer to the situation where data is stored in one or more separate computer file defined and managed by different application program.

While
Database approach share collection of logically related data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).